# Adding more than 1 arg into a list python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to create a function that can get me the coordinates of all the towns in an array using geolocator.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
def getCoord(towns):  
    result = []      #creating empty list here because I need an output of more than 1 row
    for i in towns:
        address = i
        geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="sg_explorer")
        location = geolocator.geocode(address)
        latitude = location.latitude
        longitude = location.longitude
        result.extend([i, latitude, longitude])   
        print(i, latitude, longitude)
    return(i, latitude, longitude)
```

I read that .extend is able to take more than 1 argument, but the same issue pops up when I use .append - that's it's not able to take more than 1.

All I want to achieve is an output with:

Town Name | Latitude |  Longitude

which I can then convert to a df to be stored.

Am so tempted to just copy paste the print results to an excel file then import it in again but also want to find out what is wrong with my code.

Thanks

Comment: `return result`.

Comment: You could also use `dict`, and use the town names as the keys. Many possible solution here

Comment: Instead of extending append new list to the result and then return result. Like result.append([i, latitude, longitude])

Comment: Experiment with a couple of smaller pieces of code.  1) a function with loop that creates a `result` list, and then *returns* it; 2) compare list `append` and `extend`.  Look up both methods, and make sure you understand the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Using a dictionary makes it quite simple to map town names to their coordinates:

```
def getCoord(towns):  
    result = {}      #creating empty list here because I need an output of more than 1 row
    for address in towns:
        geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="sg_explorer")
        location = geolocator.geocode(address)
        result[i] = [location.latitude, location.longitude]
    return result

towns = ['Washington', 'Paris', 'Tokyo']    
townCoords = getCoord(towns)
for town, coords in townCoords.items():
    print (town, coords)
    # This prints something like this: 
    # Washington (1.01 2.02)
    # Paris (3.03 4.04)
    # Tokyo (5.05 6.06)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is problem in your code you are not returning list of results, in place of extend use append if you want to get output something like that `result = [[town, lat, long], [town, lat, long]]`

here is your code for same

```
 def getCoord(towns):  
  result = []    
  for i in towns:
    address = i
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="sg_explorer")
    location = geolocator.geocode(address)
    latitude = location.latitude
    longitude = location.longitude
    result.append([i, latitude, longitude]) #append values into result to create nested list   
    print(i, latitude, longitude)
  return result # return result here
```